# What could be the reason why css does not work in Chrome but works in Opera?

Tags: python, css, django, static

When I tried to add styles to the Django project, they do not work in Chrome, but work in Opera. CSS are very simple, for example, margin-top should be supported by any Chrome:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin-top.asp

But Chrome does not see it, unlike the Opera. Tell me, please, what could be the problem?

I took this project as a basis:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Home_page

In **locallibrary\catalog\static\css\styles.css** I have following code:

```
.sidebar-nav {
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color: #87CEEB;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}


.container-fluid {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

In **locallibrary\catalog\templates\base_generic.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

{% block title %}<title>Test</title>{% endblock %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
      {% block sidebar %}
      <div class="sidebar-nav">
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <li>User: {{ user.get_username }}</li>

          <li><a href="{% url 'logout'%}?next={{request.path}}">Logout</a></li>
          {% else %}
          <li><a href="{% url 'login'%}?next={{request.path}}">Login</a></li>
          {% endif %}
          <hr>

          <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'books' %}">All books</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'authors' %}">All authors</a></li>

          <hr>

          <li><a href="{% url 'trips' %}">Всі відрядження</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'my-trips' %}">Мої відрядження</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'trip_new' %}" class="top-menu"> Подати заявку на відрядження 
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'search' %}" class="top-menu"> Пошук відряджень <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'trip_my' %}">Всі відрядження2</a></li>


          <hr>

          <li><a href="{% url 'author_create' %}">Create author</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'post_share' %}">Share this post</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'export_users_csv' %}">Export all users</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'attachment_email' %}">attachment email</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'my-borrowed' %}">My Borrowed</a></li>




      </div>
     {% endblock %}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 ">
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}

          {% block pagination %}
             {% if is_paginated %}
                 <div class="pagination">
                     <span class="page-links">
                         {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                             <a href="{{ request.path }}?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                         {% endif %}
                     <span class="page-current">
                         Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
                     </span>
                     {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                         <a href="{{ request.path }}?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                     {% endif %}
                      </span>
                 </div>
             {% endif %}
          {% endblock %}

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In **locallibrary\locallibrary\settings.py**:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: When you say doesnt see it, do you mean the whole file doesnt get loaded, as in returns a 404, or do you mean the css doesnt render properly?

Comment: Ok, so which styles isnt it rendering properly?

Comment: Does not render properly in Chrome. In Opera everything is Ok.

Comment: In Chrome, no style rendering properly. There is no "skyblue" background, no margin-top: 20px

Comment: I dont think this is a python/django issue. different browsers render things differently. Did you try to substitute the background-color with its hex variant as in `background-color: #87CEEB;`

Comment: It does not help. The strange thing is that the css "margin-top" as I understand is as simple as possible. But it also does not work.

Comment: Could you please add you styles.css and html to your question. would help if i could try it at my end.

Comment: Please find full code for styles.css and base_generic.html in question.

Comment: renders the same for me :s, it works just fine

Comment: which version of chrome are you on?

Comment: version 71.0.3578.98

Comment: I should have just closed Chrome and opened it again.